# Error in Chrome with Bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a bootstrap carousel with multiple items in angular. but it works in Internet Explorer and Firefox but Chrome does not work.

[in firefox and explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8roJ.png)

[in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpzZy.png)

I do not know that it could be failing. What will be the error or perhaps some configuration. Thanks for the help

This is the code Carousel:

```
<h1>ANGULAR:</h1>
   <div ng-app='angularRoutingApp'>
   <div  ng-controller="ruta_hbo_max" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="10000" id="hbo_mas">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="data in datos  track by $index">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <p>{{data.ruta}}</p>
                  <a><img ng-src="{{ data.ruta }}"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

and this query to display the images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert("entrando d");
        $('.item').each(function(){
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length)
                {
              alert();
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

            for (var i=0;i<2;i++) 
            {
                next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) 
            {
              next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using ui-bootstrap? doesn't look like it, you can drop the bootstrap.js dependency and just load the bootstrap.css and load ui-bootstrap-tpls.js from the ui-bootstrap project then you can use the directives in there for applying interactivity to elements from bootstrap.  As an alternative checkout angular strap.

Comment: When using angular all the DOM manipulation should really just be handled inside of directives, this makes it easy to see from the markup what things are applied to a given element and eliminates the need to load full blown jQuery, it also makes it so the code in your controllers/services/factories/filters/etc. don't directly interact with the DOM and can be tested as plain old javascript objects.